# No matching distribution found for 'package' in python wheel

Tags: python-2.7, pip, setup.py, pypi, python-wheel

I have written a python package called `lyrico` and uploaded the source dist and wheel to testpypi site.

[lyrico](https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/lyrico)

But when I try to install it from there using following command it gives errors:

```
pip install -i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi lyrico
```

Error logged in cmd-prompt:

```
Collecting lyrico
Using cached https://testpypi.python.org/packages/py2/l/lyrico/lyrico-0.2.5-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting mutagen (from lyrico)
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mutagen (from lyrico) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mutagen (from lyrico)
```

It is unable to find the dependency `mutagen` in wheel I uploaded. I have included dependencies in my `setup.py`:

```
install_requires = [
    'mutagen',
    'glob2',
    'beautifulsoup4',
    'win-unicode-console >= 0.4'
],
```

Weird thing is that if go to testPyPi [page](https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/lyrico) and manually download and install the wheel using (after cd to the containing dir):

```
pip install lyrico-0.2.5-py2-none-any.whl
```

it works and installs all the dependencies as well. 
I am using Python 2.7.11 on a Windows7 system. Can someone please tell what is wrong or if the error is reproduce-able?

Comment: When I looked at this question, if finalyl occured to me where my mistake was - I was trying to create a new package. I registered it via twine, but forgot to do proper `twine upload`, which solved my problem. Maybe it isn't your case, but I'm leaving this here in case anyone else needs it.